# Extreme values of a two-variable polynomial

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

Is it possible to find a two-variable polynomial which has only two extreme values on the whole plane, one is a local maximum, another is a local minimum, and the local maximum is less than the local minimum?

Comment: Nice question, just a remark: It is not too hard to give an argument that one can find a smooth function with this property, but I am not sure how to make it into a polynomial.

Comment: I am not sure, hence not an answer, but a comment. However, intuitively I would think the answer is no. At least, in a 1-variable domain it cannot be done.

Comment: Consider the values of the polynomial along the line joining the two extreme points ...

Comment: One-dimensional max/min problems are very different from two-dimensional ones, and looking at values on a line is not going to help very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here is an example. Pick any odd degree $5$ polynomial $f$ with critical points $\pm x_1$ and $\pm x_2$, where $0<x_1<x_2$, such that $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$. This automatically implies that $f$ has local maxima at $-x_2$ and $x_1$, and local minima at $-x_1$ and $x_2$, with $f(-x_2) < 0 < f(x_2)$. (As an example, $f(x) = x^5 - 2x^3 + 1.1 x$ works, but there are lots of such polynomials.)

Now define a polynomial of two variables by $F(x,y) = f(x) + xy^2$. The partial derivatives are
$$
F_x(x,y) = f'(x) + y^2 \quad \text{ and } \quad F_y(x,y) = 2xy,
$$
so the critical points satisfy $x=0$ or $y=0$. Since $f'(0)>0$, there are no critical points with $y=0$, so the only critical points are solutions to $y=0$ and $f'(x) = 0$, i.e., the critical points of $f$ on the $x$-axis. The Hessian matrix (of second-order partials) at those points is
$$
HF(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} f''(x) & 0 \\ 0 & 2x \end{bmatrix},
$$
so the second derivative test shows that there is a local maximum at $(-x_2, 0)$, a local minimum at $(x_2,0)$, and saddle points at $(\pm x_1,0)$. Lastly, 
$$F(-x_2,0) = f(-x_2) < 0 < f(x_2) = F(x_2, 0),$$
as desired.

Here is a plot of the graph of one example, $F(x,y) = x^5 - 2x^3 + 1.1x + xy^2$:[image]

Comment: A nice example! Thank you very much!

Comment: If saddle points are considered critical, it is false.

Comment: @JoelSjögren: Sure, but the question was about a polynomial with two extreme values, no restriction on the number of critical points.

Comment: I see, I got lost in the vocabulary.

Comment: @JoelSjögren: It would be an interesting (and harder) question if there is an example without saddle points. I would think that there are smooth examples, but I have no idea whether one can find a polynomial with that property.

Comment: @LukasGeyer You can always send the saddles to infinity having only the two centers as the singularities at the finite part. For example $x^5/5−(5x^3)/3+4x+xy^2$ has saddles at $(\pm 1,0)$. By making $y↦y(x^2−1)^2+1$ you get $x^5/5−(5x^3)/3+4x+x(y(x^2−1)^2+1)^2$ with the properties you want!